# Query and partitionColumn - Spark Data read from Databricks JDBC end point

Tags: python, pyspark, jdbc, databricks

I am trying to read from a databricks JDBC end point using PySpark and write it to PostgreSQL. I am fetching 2 million records. To improve performance I have added a row_number column to my query and using it to partition the read. Below is my code and sql.

```
src_df= spark.read.format("jdbc"). \
        option("url", url). \
        option("dbtable", sqlquery). \
        option("fetchSize", 20000). \
        option("partitionColumn", "row_number"). \
        option("lowerBound", 1). \
        option("upperBound", 60000). \
        option("numPartitions", 8). \
        option("driver", driver). \
        option("user", user). \
        option("password", PAT_token).load()
```

I am defining the sql in a config file that I am retrieving in the code. sql entry from the .ini is as below

```
sqlquery= (select
        row_number() over(order by (select null)) as row_number,
        artifact1_name,
        artifact2_name) as q1
```

Since I do not want the row_number to be written into the PosgreSQL DB I am dropping it as below.

```
final_df=src_df.drop("row_number")
```

However the problem is that the src_df.count is coming as 0. I am not sure if this is the issue with databricks JDBC or the way I have defined the query in the .ini file. The code without any partitioning works fine against the same databricks end point. The below works fine without any issues.

```
src_df = spark.read.format("jdbc").\
         option("url", url).\
         option("query", sqlquery).\
         option("fetchSize", 30000).\
         option("driver", driver).\
         option("user", user).\
         option("password", pwd).load()
```

My understanding is that using partitionColumn, upperbound and lowerbound does not filter any data. Any help or pointers in this regard is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: just to be sure - are you getting output with only the url, dbtable, driver, user and password ?

Comment: Yes I am getting the output.

Answer (score 0):

The `sqlquery` you're using is generating the `row_number` column dynamically. For the parallelized reading to work properly `partitionColumn` needs to be a column on a physical table (spark generates a bunch of queries with where statements on that column using provided ranges of values).

If you add that column to the physical table, or use other existing numeric/date column, it should work.

Comment: Since there was no column that could be used for partitioning in the physical table I had added this row number to the dataframe. My understanding was that spark would consider the columns in the dataframe for partitioning